# What technologies does ChromeOS use to secure saved passwords?

Tags: passwords, chrome

I have read that Chrome will use the system's native credential tools to manage saved passwords (e.g. KeyChain on OSX, libsecret on Linux/GNOME etc). Does anyone know what tools are used on ChromeOS?

Comment: ChromeOS is Linux, so I presume it uses a keyring implementation that works on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

ChromeOS is build on Linux only, so the developers take the advantage of the existing solutions available for encrypting the user data AND make it **automatic** and **mandatory**.

If we talk about options available to ChromeOS developers (because of the fact that it was built on Linux) was --

- Block based Encryption
- File System based Encryption
- Whole disk Encryption
- Whole data partition Encryption

File system based encryption was chosen for encrypting the home directories of all the users. Encrypting user's home directories means all the data (including cached history, cookies, saved passwords, and other) will be encrypted by default and will be transparent to the user.

If we talk about specific tool (or package) which ChromeOS uses to encrypt the saved password (as saved passwords are also stored in the user's home directory), **[eCryptfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECryptfs)** (**E**nterprise **Crypt**ographic **F**ile**s**ystem) is a package which do the encryption in ChromeOS.

Hope this explains your query.

References - 
1. https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/chromiumos-design-docs/protecting-cached-user-data#Appendix_D_Designs_considered

Comment: That's not what the OP asked. If I'm understanding correctly the question was about credential management, not file encryption.

Comment: @Eclipse... I completely understood what Brad asked..... Just go through the reference and you will understand the things.